# ERROR: Error installing goliath: goliath requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

```
sudo gem install goliath
```

giving error

```
ERROR:  Error installing goliath:   goliath requires Ruby version >= 1
```

but when tried `ruby -v` it shows

```
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [i686-linux]
```

Why is it so??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common error when installing gems via `sudo` while Ruby is installed with rvm. If this is the case, then sudo triggers the original system Ruby which tends to be 1.8.7 and therefore blocks.

So, if you're using rvm stop using `sudo gem install xxx` just use `gem install goliath` and you should be fine.